# vb2010 getting name values from multiple buttons

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

At the moment, I have a button that sends a value to another form and displays result in a label. The problem is, I have 20 buttons that are labeled a to w that need to be coded and I am stumped as to how I can pass values from multiple buttons. Would it be a case statement in the form being passed to? I am a new user to VB.Net and still finding my way so any help would be gratefully received. I have included code sample for the first button 'A'. Thanks

frmMain

```
Private Sub btnA_MouseDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles btnA.MouseDown
        If (e.Button = MouseButtons.Right) Then
            'Dim curButton As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
            'frmRacks.buttonName = curButton.Name 'Dynamic alternative to frmRacks.buttonName = "A"
            frmRacks.buttonName = "A"
            frmRacks.Show()
        ElseIf (e.Button = MouseButtons.Left) Then
            MessageBox.Show("To be coded")
        End If
    End Sub
```

frmRacks

```
Public Class frmRacks
    Public buttonName As String
    Private Sub racksfrm_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        lblRacks.Text = buttonName

    End Sub
```

EDIT: New project

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim button1 As Button = New Button
        Dim button2 As Button = New Button
        Dim button3 As Button = New Button

        With button1
            .Name = "button1"
            .Left = 0
            AddHandler .MouseDown, AddressOf btn_MouseDown
            'Add remaining properties for button1
        End With

        With button2
            .Name = "button2"
            .Left = 100
            AddHandler .MouseDown, AddressOf btn_MouseDown
            'Add remaining properties for button2
        End With

        With button3
            .Name = "button3"
            .Left = 200
            AddHandler .MouseDown, AddressOf btn_MouseDown
            'Add remaining properties for button3
        End With

        Me.Controls.Add(button1)
        Me.Controls.Add(button2)
        Me.Controls.Add(button3)

    End Sub

    Private Sub btn_MouseDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)

        Dim curButton As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
        Dim curButtonName As String = curButton.Name 'This string would change on account of the button you have clicked
        Form2.buttonName = curButtonName
        Form2.Show()
        'MessageBox.Show("You clicked the button called " & curButtonName.ToUpper)
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Form2
    Public buttonName As String
    Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        lblRacks.Text = buttonName
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You have asked this question before and I see that, at least one of the answers there, gives a code allowing you to perform what apparently you want. Perhaps there is a misunderstanding (either you not understanding exactly the answers or I (or the answerers) not understanding what you want). Let me try to clarify all this: what is btnA_MouseDown? The click event method associated with all the buttons?

Comment: @varocarbas Where have I asked a question about mulitple buttons? It is the click event assoctiated with only button at the moment button 'A'. Thanks

Comment: Then perhaps this is the misunderstanding: your last question/answer works for one button and for 1000 buttons. You can associate btnA_MouseDown to as many buttons as you wish and retrieve the corresponding name (not sure why you are hardcoding it now frmRacks.buttonName = "A")

Comment: @varocarbas sorry I do not understand your answer. Could you provide code sample please. Thanks

Comment: @varocarbas I am hardcoing because the value of btnA = A and it I didn't do that, then the value or name would be btnA. I would have called it just 'A', but I prefer to prefix with control type. Thanks

Comment: Please, open a new project, paste this code into the main class, execute it and tell me your impressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have a sample code which hopefully will help you to get clearer ideas:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim button1 As Button = New Button
    Dim button2 As Button = New Button
    Dim button3 As Button = New Button

    With button1
        .Name = "button1"
        .Left = 0
        AddHandler .MouseDown, AddressOf btn_MouseDown
        'Add remaining properties for button1
    End With

    With button2
        .Name = "button2"
        .Left = 100
        AddHandler .MouseDown, AddressOf btn_MouseDown
        'Add remaining properties for button2
    End With

    With button3
        .Name = "button3"
        .Left = 200
        AddHandler .MouseDown, AddressOf btn_MouseDown
        'Add remaining properties for button3
    End With

    Me.Controls.Add(button1)
    Me.Controls.Add(button2)
    Me.Controls.Add(button3)

End Sub

Private Sub btn_MouseDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)

    Dim curButton As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)

    Dim curButtonName As String = curButton.Name 'This string would change on account of the button you have clicked

    MessageBox.Show("You clicked the button called " & curButtonName.ToUpper)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for that. However, I have one question. Am I correct in thinking after reading your code, that your form1_load would be my frmMain and Mousedown sub would be my frm\racks to capture event? Thanks

Comment: @user1532468 This code intends to provide a general approach which you should understand. It adds buttons to the main form (you can replace it with any form, the forms you mention, for example); while defining the buttons, it associates the corresponding events (MouseDown in this case, but you can do the same with any other event); instead creating as many methods as buttons, it uses the same method for all of them and takes advantage from the sender argument which is the current button (and retrieves the property you want .Name). Are all these ideas clear to you?

Comment: Nope. I stated in my question that I am a new user and just started getting to grips with actual coding after 2 weeks of reading and tutorials. Thanks

Comment: @user1532468 OK... for example in your code, instead writing "frmRacks.buttonName = "A"" (what is hardcoding), you can do the following...

Comment: @user1532468 Dim curButton As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button) frmRacks.buttonName = curButton.Name That is, the sender argument gives you all the information about the given button. In my code, I am associating the same method to three different buttons; the sender argument will store every time the information for every button and that's why if you execute my code, different names will be displayed (even though no hardcoding is happening)

Comment: @user1532468 and you can do the same with any other property of the button... curButton in my code represents the button currently being clicked (button1, button2 or button3)

Comment: I have tried as per your last comment: Dim curButton As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)frmracks.buttonName = curButton.Name but this throws an error. End of statement expected. Thanks

Comment: @user1532468 Please... I meant in two different lines (I cannot write this in the comments). You should replace the hardcoding part with the .Name property from the given button (curButton)

Comment: @user1532468 I have added two comments to your code to show what I meant: these two lines should replace your frmRacks.buttonName = "A"

Comment: How do I capture that .Name in frmRacks? do I just declare a variable of curButton in frmRacks. Thanks

Comment: @user1532468 let's speed up this a bit and don't forget about the exact point of SO and my help (providing some hints to more or less knowledgeable programmers); if you don't know even the basics, you shouldn't be asking here and I shouldn't be helping you. Let's do a last try... my code is clear and works without any problem; please, execute it, understand what is its point, what I am trying to explain. If you don't get anything, please, ask me and I will try to answer you. Once you will understand this code, you will be able to know how to retrieve properties...

Comment: ... from an event method (even to attach event methods at runtime). Once you know that, you would understand how to retrieve the name of the given button dynamically and without hardcoding. Once you know the name of the given button, I hope that you will now how to pass this name to the target variable (frmRacks.buttonName). Please, make an effort to not make me regret having helped you... As said, go step by step and ask any specific issue you don't understand (firstly in my code and in how it retrieves button names at runtime)

Comment: Yes I understand. But I have run your code and in frmRacks the label is blank after amending the code as per edit. I shall include as an edit what I am using now as a new project. Thanks

Comment: @user1532468 I have corrected your code. You weren't assigning the value to the other form public variable, what did you expect to happen?

Comment: You have been more than helpful and I thank you for your time and patience. You never know, The next time I am here, I may be able to help you. All the best.

Comment: @user1532468 No problem. I do expect anyone in a position to help (me or anyone else) to do that. In any case, SO has some rules and the help here is conditioned: you need to have a minimum knowledge and do some work by your own (= be a programmer, not someone wanting help). Also this is not about you; but about future readers finding this information useful. You have to make an effort to fulfil all these requirements (if you want to keep getting help here). Anyway... I guess that your ideas are clear now and your problem is solved (and that this is the right answer for your question)

Comment: @user1532468 PS: I personally (and quite a few people like me) don't provide help under these conditions (you got information more than enough in your previous question and in this one your ideas weren't still too clear); mainly because I don't have to be here wasting my time to explain something you should learn by your own. This has been an exceptional situation. Learn from it and don't repeat this behaviour (at least, if you want to get further help from me).